# Segmentation fault at the end of an array of strings in a while loop

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop, segmentation-fault

Here's part of my code

```
char **images; // An array of strings filled with valid data

while(*images)
{
    printf("input image = %s\n", *images);
    images++;
}
```

I'm expecting it to exit the loop when the end of the array is reached but it still goes inside the loop and crashes. Please suggest how to fix this issue. The number of elements in the array is not fixed.

Comment: what does images point to?  how is it initialized?

Comment: Unless you explicitly add a null pointer last in the "array", there's no way to know where it might end.

Comment: Also remember that by doing `images++` you lose the original pointer. Unless you save it there's no way to get it back.

Comment: You need add NULL (0) at the end of image to break from loop.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The code will not know how to stop since the while loop is always true, i.e not zero. Even if you run past the end of the array into unmarked address space the code will keep going and then segfault as you suggest.

You should always close off string data with a marker such as "\0" and perform a check in the while loop i.e:

```
while ( strcmp(*images, "\0") != 0 )
```

or you should know the size of the **images array and stop after reading the last item. For this reason its probably better to use a for loop instead of a while loop. The strcmp version above is much less efficient. The for loop should be very efficient.

Comment: Note: `while ( strcmp(*images, "\0") != 0 )` same as `while (strcmp(*images, ""))` and IMO, easier to code/review/read.

Comment: Concerning "strcmp version above is much less efficient." --> Perhaps.  Compilers are very smart and good ones "understand" C standard library functions such as `strcmp()` and emit efficient  code for `while ( strcmp(*images, "\0") != 0 )` as if `while ( (*images)[0])` was coded.